# Date on date strip need to link to database

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if this is possible or not, I need to get the dates ie JAN | FEB | MAR etc so when you click on them I can link them to a database search so it goes to a different page. At the moment it just show the dates

[image]

```
<body> 
<!-- body code goes here --> 
  <div class="scrollable-nav-inner"> 
    <nav class="scrollable-nav"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><a class="font" id="date"></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </nav> 
  </div>
  <script>
  function showDate() {
    const months= ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var newMonths = "";
    var d = new Date();

    // Find current day, month and last day of month
    var currentDay = d.getDate();
    var lastDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59).getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();

    for (var i = month + 1; i <= 11; i++) {
        newMonths = newMonths +" | " + months[i];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < month; i++) {
        newMonths = newMonths +" | " + months[i];
    }

    var str = "<span style='color:green'>" + months[month] + " " + currentDay + " - " + lastDay + "</span> " + newMonths;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = str;
  }

  window.onload = showDate();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail in what you're trying to achieve, what doesn't work, what are you stuck on etc - if you're seeking help. Just now there's no question you only told us what you want to achieve. A good resource to help you write a complete question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok 

At the moment I have got the code to say the Day 17 - 31 and the next 11 month in order as shown in the photo.

(Which someone from this site did for me a long time ago)


What I am trying to achieve is when you click on the Dates, they each have a separate link which can then be coded to the database to show different search results for that month.


Hope that makes sense

Comment: Don't post additional information in a comment, edit the question.